# Example of HTTP Pipelining vs no pipelining

Tags: http

Can someone give me a concrete example of HTTP with/without pipelining? I always think that both methods can handle multiple requests/responses, except for pipelining case, it only uses one socket, which means only one connection. In contrast, without pipelining, each socket (connection) is unique to each request, so it has the overhead of opening/closing socket. However, with high speed internet today, the difference is negligible. Is that true?

Comment: @JulianReschke That should probably have been an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

No, even without pipelining, HTTP/1.1 will use a single socket for multiple requests; one after the other. And no, opening a new socket is expensive because it causes additional roundtrips.

Comment: A client could have simultaneous connections to a given server(http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4). I think you answered the difference between one connection with and without pipeline whereas @amumu asked the performance comparison between one connection with pipeline and multiple connections without pipeline.